# Having issue with react-native-paper in react-native-web platform

Tags: monorepo, react-native-web, react-native-paper, nomachine-nx

I have followed react native paper documentation for User on the Web.
When I try to serve it gave me an error

https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/using-on-the-web.html

While try to run it return error

[nx run website:server issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIXqn.png)

[npm run web issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNdn4.png)

Is this Nx monorepo support issue